# How to read image from LocalFolder without using await in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, win-universal-app, windows

I am developing a windows app. There is a model class with a property `CoverSource` of type `ImageSource` and a property `FileName` of type `string`. Both of them are data bidden to views so I can't make their getters or setters async functions. Now I want that in the setter of `FileName`, an async function will be called and after that the `CoverSource` will be set asynchronously by reading file from `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. I am a newbie to C# and get little help from Google. So how to write such a async function and call it with callback, just something like that in Javascript?

Comment: Why you have to write it in getter setter? Set it somewhere else. For example in OnNavigatedTo or OnLoaded method

Comment: Load the picture in another method, and on its callback set your property and raise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of conflicting requirements here. First, the Windows platform (just like any other modern mobile platform) requires your view updates to be synchronous. Blocking the UI thread is not considered acceptable; any updates must be immediate. Secondly, reading a file is an I/O-based operation, and thus naturally asynchronous. So that forces you into a non-blocking approach.

The answer is to realize that both requirements are correct. The UI *must* be updated immediately, and file I/O *must* take an arbitrary amount of time. So, the proper design is to think about what your UI looks like while the I/O is in progress, and then purposefully design for that scenario.

Something like this should work:

```
public string FileName
{
  get { return fileName; }
  set
  {
    fileName = value;
    LoadFileAsync();
  }
}

private async Task LoadFileAsync()
{
  try
  {
    CoverSource = ...; // "Loading" image or something.
    var image = await ...;
    CoverSource = image;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    CoverSource = ...; // "Error" image or something.
  }
}
```

I have an [MSDN article on async data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) that goes into much more detail, and introduces a `NotifyTaskCompletion` type that takes care of a lot of the boilerplate code with this approach.